# Scroll a RelativeLayout when it contains custom Views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to make scrollable RelativeLayout, that contains some custom Views. This is the plan of cinema hall, i have x, y coordinates of places and it's width and height (that are just rectangales, actually). I just put it into this RelativeLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10px">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/scrollable_places"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I put it like this:

```java
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.scrollable_places);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(place.getWidth(),
 place.getHeight());
    params.leftMargin = place.getX();
    params.topMargin = place.getY();
    layout.addView(new Seat(context, place), params);
```

Seat class looks like this:

```
public class Seat extends View {

private Place place;
private boolean isRed = false;

public Seat(Context context, Place place) {
    super(context);
    this.place = place;
    setOnClickListener(new OnSeatClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!isRed)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
}

    protected void setRed() {
        isRed = true;
    }

    private class OnSeatClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Seat) view).setRed();
            view.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Views are drawing perfectly. But I have ann array of views, and when some of them go out of the screen, scrollView didn't work, there is no scroll on the screen. Have you any ideas how can I make this layout scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try following xml file. It will work on all the devices.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/scrollable_places"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In scroll view you have written `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of using wrap_content five specific height size eg `android:layout_height="100dip"`

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But how can i make this layout expand to the whole screen by width? If i'll use HorizontalScrollWiew for example. From phone to phone width are different

Comment: Oh, i found it. I just needed to write something like                   scrollView.getLayoutParams().width = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()